# How to press enter key using appium, C#?

Tags: c#, appium

I'm trying to press enter using appim, but nothings work it. I just want to send a text and press an enter key.
This is my code

```
`public void sendElement(string element) {
          
            //Se envía el proveedor y se presiona enter
            sendText(myTextbox, element);
            //driver.PressKeyCode(WindowsKeyCode.Enter);
       

            //driver.PressKeyCode(13);
            //driver.PressKeyCode(0x00000042);
            // enter.SendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.Enter);


            //driver.PressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.Enter);
            // driver.PressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
            //driver.LongPressKeyCode(66);


            //driver.PressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KeycodeNumpad_ENTER);
            
        }`
```

I want to press enter after I write the text in the textbox. I tried using '\n', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichTextBox instead of TextBox

Or you can try this code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
    }
```